# Context free grammar for $bin(n)bin(n+1)^R$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

It is pretty hard for me to understand, how binary representation of number may be context free. This language $L=\{bin(n)bin(n+1)^R : n \geq 0\}$ is context free.

[Here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs481/2001fa/pdffiles/SS06.pdf), at 1.b, is a PDA which describes this language, so it is context free. I've tried to construct a context free grammar for this one, but I have no idea when to even start. How can I express a CFG binary representation of a number? I would be very glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to 01 \mid 1A1 \mid 1B1 \\
&A \to 1A0 \mid 0 \\
&B \to 1B1 \mid 0B0 \mid 0C1 \\
&C \to 1C0 \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Explanation:

- $A$ generates $1^n 0^{n+1}$, and so $1A1$ generates $1^{n+1} 0^{n+1}1$, which handles numbers whose binary expansion is $1^{n+1}$.
- $C$ generates $1^n 0^n$, and so $0C1$ generates $01^n 0^n1$.
- $B$ generates $w01^n0^n1w^R$, and so $1B1$ generates $1w01^n0^n1w^R1$, which handles numbers whose binary expansion is $1w01^n$.
- Finally, $01$ handles $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know meybe grammar for $L = \{bin(n)bin(n+1) : n \geq 0\}$ ? It's same, but without reversing $bin(n+1)$

Comment: That language isn't context-free.

Comment: Do you meybe know word for pumping lemma, which I could use to prove that it is not context free ?

Comment: It's a very standard exercise. You can also try reducing to the language $a^nb^mc^nd^m$.